# Google Chrome - how to open new window, in background

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am sorry for bad written question title, I don't know how to ask this. Let me give you a little background on the problem. What I have is a javascript script, that works on a website. It opens new tabs, does something, closes them and repeats it until I close the website. Problem is, when I open and start the script, I can't do anything with my pc, since when new tab is open, Windows 10 automatically focuses it and opens chrome.

My question is, can I do it somehow in the background? For example, start the scripts, leave chrome open and let it do its work, but use different browser for other things, without chrome poping up every time new tab is open.

I can edit the javascript I have. I use **window.open()** in order to open new tabs. Is there some kind of parameter, argument or anything else, that will force window.open to just open new website in window, something like popunder, without google chrome having to maximize and focus me on it?

Comment: So why use a new window? Why not an iframe or a web worker? Pop behind windows are frowned upon since that is what people used to do to hide ads and other content.

Comment: Are you asking us to create a pop under? Doesn't everybody hate those?

Comment: Well, something like that, but only I use the website, since I run it to do some tasks instead of me... :D

Comment: Then you should look into web workers if you need processing to happen in the background. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with that

```
var url = "yourURL.html";
window.open(url, "s", "width= 640, height= 480, left=0, top=0, 
resizable=yes, toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, 
menubar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=no, copyhistory=no").blur();
window.focus();
```

Using blur/focus on window object you can manage which one appears active from time to time.